# Why binary files serialization has certain performance and size benefits?

Tags: binary-data, binary-serialization

Why binary files serialization is faster to serialize and capture relatively small amount of disk-space in compare to text files serialization?

Comment: 1) Text format only uses a subset of the storage capacity of each byte (some character codes are reserved).  2) binary serialization can often take place in the actual binary format that the variable has natively, saving the need to convert to and from text.

Comment: - also, if you try to actually take a look at some examples of data serialized as XML, the overhead should be fairly obvious. Depending on  the data types involved, it is not uncommon to see the size of the XML meta data (tags, attribute names, and so on) dwarf the actual payload size by factors of 3 or more.